# Remove directories from a file with list of directories

Tags: bash, shell, rm

I have a list of directories in a text file and each of them need to be deleted. How can I read in that list into the command (`rm -r` or `rmdir`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "more correct" solution would be the following:

```
xargs -I{} rm -r {} < files
```

This calls `rm -r`, where `{}` is replaced with the file name.

---

Why? Piping files with spaces to `xargs` will result in wrong arguments. Let's say your list of files looks like this:

```
/path/to/file 1
/path/to/file_2
```

Then `xargs rm -r < list.txt` would try to delete `/path/to/file`, `1` and `/path/to/file_2`. Definitely not what you want. Always be aware of spaces in paths when piping from and to UNIX / Linux commands.

Comment: What is the `-I{}` doing here? Docs say "replace string". Also, does this work if the file paths from the deletion list have spaces in them?

Comment: File name too long

Comment: From the manpage: *"Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input."* Most importantly, it says, *"Unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character."* So, the `< files` makes `xargs` receive the list of files as standard input. Then, it calls the initial argument, `rm -r`, on every line (= file name) received. With the `-I` option the splitting is done based on newlines rather than spaces, which means that this operation is safe for file paths with spaces in them. I don't understand your other comment.

Comment: the list is too long. if i have 1000+ files to delete its too long for xargs

Comment: You can probably then do something like this: `cat files | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -r` – this replaces the newlines with ASCII null characters. `xargs` will then call `rm` for each of the received lines separately.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have paths **with spaces** in file list.txt - one path per line. Then the following way of invoking xargs will preserve spaces:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -d \\n rm -r
```

Comment: this doesn't suffer from argument list too long errors. upvoting.